# Run Maven, Gradle or other batch-based script from Java (and then Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, eclipse-plugin

I am making Eclipse [plugin](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.maven) that run alternative build from within Eclipse
(e.g. for project that have both `pom.xml` and `build.gradle` do run with `mvn package` or `gradle build`)

But entry point for both of them are batch `.bat` files on Windows and bash on Linux.
For Windows running from Java would look like

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start mvn");
```

but that will start new window, while I want it to see running in Eclipse Console.

There must be something [like](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) but in Eclipse way I guess. **How to run such script from Eclipse and see output in Console?**
This is meant to be alternative and not dependent on m2e and Gradle Integration.

Comment: For discussion why there is https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/117 . Looking for a way how to implement.

Comment: The proper way to programmatically run a Gradle build is to use the Gradle tooling API.

Comment: That may be specific solution for Gradle only. Additionally looking at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/embedding.html and http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/package-summary.html one can say it is for embedding gradle, that quite opposite to lightweight launchers that are planned.

Comment: It's almost always the way to go. Uses Gradle's official bootstrap mechanism (i.e. Gradle doesn't need to be preinstalled), automatically chooses the correct Gradle version if specified by the build, runs in its own process (Gradle daemon), is very responsive (process stays alive between commands), supports advanced interaction with the build, is *the* supported way for tools to integrate with Gradle, etc.

Comment: I think this is the link - http://goo.gl/0WT7hN for creating Eclipse Console. In one of the projects we had this code to invoke maven or gradle - you can grab the stream & point it to the Console `final Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
                    .command(mvnPath, "clean", "test")
                    .directory(projectDirectory)
                    .redirectErrorStream(true)
                    .start();` and then grabbed the input stream - `InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
           final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did just as for Node.js using full path to maven installation (that should be selected in Preferences). But it is weird that I needed to pass `JAVA_HOME` and `M2_HOME`, because otherwise I get `JAVA_HOME not found` or `M2_HOME not found`, just like when maven is not yet set up:

```
ERROR: M2_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation
```

related code

```
public class LaunchConfigurationDelegate implements ILaunchConfigurationDelegate {

@Override
public void launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode,
        ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {


    // skipped some argument processing

    envp[idx++] = "JAVA_HOME=" + System.getProperty("java.home");         
    envp[idx++] = "M2_HOME=" + System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME");

    String[] cmds = {};
    cmds = cmdLine.toArray(cmds);
    // Launch a process to run/debug. See also #71 (output is less or no output)
    Process p = DebugPlugin.exec(cmds, workingPath, envp);
    // no way to get private p.handle from java.lang.ProcessImpl
    RuntimeProcess process = (RuntimeProcess)DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, p, Constants.PROCESS_MESSAGE);
```

**Is there some more beautiful way to do that?** Please add as an answer.

UPDATE: This does not fully solves the problem, see [Java - process launched with Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cannot create temp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397170/java-process-launched-with-runtime-getruntime-exec-cannot-create-temp-file)

Comment: Continued in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360995/processes-launched-from-java-with-runtime-getruntime-exec-cant-get-access-t