# Processes Launched from Java with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` can't get access to file system places

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, eclipse-rcp

Process Launched from Java with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` has less permissions 
and I don't see description for that in JavaDocs and how to manage that.

**How to ensure that launched process has the same environment and permissions?**

More details:

Writing lightweight Eclipse plugins for [maven](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.maven) and [gradle](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.gradle). (This problem is tested not to be Eclipse related see in the end.)

I am launching `mvn` and `gradle` from within Eclipse plugin:

For gradle `gralde build` fails to create a temporary file:

[Eclipse plugin development - Gradle fails to run from Eclipse launcher: java.io.IOException: Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260657/eclipse-plugin-development-gradle-fails-to-run-from-eclipse-launcher-java-io)

For maven `D:\Progs\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\mvn.bat -X compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=runclass.Runme`

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 16:44:56+0800)
Maven home: D:\Progs\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from D:\Progs\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\weibl\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project maven-example:maven-example:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix  compile exec from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository)
```

The line above is different from the same launch from `cmd` shell where it is `[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix exec to org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin from repository central`. It is the same every time though all required jar and metadata are already downloaded.
Log continues:

```
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
3/13 KB   
7/13 KB   
10/13 KB   
3/22 KB   10/13 KB   
7/22 KB   10/13 KB   
11/22 KB   10/13 KB   
11/22 KB   12/13 KB   
15/22 KB   12/13 KB   
19/22 KB   12/13 KB   
22/22 KB   12/13 KB   

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (22 KB at 15.0 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
13/13 KB              

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 6.1 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
```

After this line there is likely write exception, because this download goes every time.
Maven reports higher level error, that it cannot get needed artifacts for `compile exec`,
though (saying once again) they are already in local maven repo:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.655s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 26 13:51:56 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix ' compile exec' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix ' compile exec' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\weibl\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

UPDATE: Made sure it is not Eclipse related. Following Java code produces similar log output as above

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

// http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html
public class MediocreExecJavac {
    private static void log(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {

            String mavenPath = "D:\\Progs\\springsource\\apache-maven-3.0.4\\bin\\mvn.bat";
            String mavenOptions  = "-X compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=runclass.Runme";

            String[] cmdLine = new String[2];
            cmdLine[0] = mavenPath;  //cmdLine.add(mavenPath);
            cmdLine[1] = mavenOptions;      //cmdLine.add(mavenOptions+" compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="+packageClass);        

            String[] envp = new String[2];
            //Map<String, String> envm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            envp[0] = "JAVA_HOME=" + System.getProperty("java.home"); //System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
            envp[1] = "M2_HOME=" + System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME");     

            File workingDirectory = null;
            String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
            log(currentDir);
            String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir"); //User working directory ; "user.home"     User home directory
            workingDirectory = new File(userDir);       
            log(workingDirectory.toString());

            //
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec(cmdLine, envp, workingDirectory);
            InputStream stdout = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
            InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);

            String line = null;
            System.out.println("<OutputStream>");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("</OutputStream>");

            System.out.println("<ErrorStream>");
            while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("</ErrorStream>");

            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
</OutputStream>
<ErrorStream>
'cmd' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
�������ļ���
</ErrorStream>
Process exitValue: 1
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the maven commands from command line without Eclipse etc.?

Comment: Yes, just read the end of the question. There is code example.

Comment: The error `plugin found for prefix ' compile exec'` looks strange. Just as a test - can you try downloading maven separately and setting the `M2_HOME` variable - rename your `%USERPROFILE%\.m2` directory and then rerun. In Windows Vista+ (including 7 & 8) when you launch a process it always runs as less permissions unless your force it to run as an administrator.

Comment: All that work perfectly well from `cmd` shell on Windows 7.
The error `No plugin found for prefix ' compile exec'` is not exact as actually there is IO error during that phase. I have already added comment about that in between log parts. See Gradle that reports correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260657/eclipse-plugin-development-gradle-fails-to-run-from-eclipse-launcher-java-io?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved for Maven and Gradle by passing a set of environment variables.

See http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/maven and http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/